# How to multiply with out looping. VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need my program to identify if the type is fruit or salad, and if it is in a good or bad shape.
Depending on that it must multiply Prcies*Stock.

So I did this code, but when it has more than 5000 lines it is really slow.
How can I do this with out loopin?

```
Sub Go()

Set Page1 = Worksheets("Page 1")

LastRow = Page1.Cells(Page1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Range("B" & i).Value = "fruit" And Range("C" & i).Value = "good" Then
    Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D" & i) * Range("I2").Value
        Else
            If Range("B" & i).Value = "fruit" And Range("C" & i).Value = "bad" Then
                Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value * Range("J2").Value
        Else
            If Range("B" & i).Value = "salad" And Range("C" & i).Value = "good" Then
                Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D" & i) * Range("I3").Value
        Else
            If Range("B" & i).Value = "salad" And Range("C" & i).Value = "bad" Then
                Range("E" & i).Value = Range("D" & i) * Range("J3").Value
        Else
             Range("E" & i).Value = "error"
            End If
            End If
            End If
End If

Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: No need for VBA here, this is doable with just worksheet formulas.

Comment: If you want to do it with VBA then get an array from the data and loop through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit (performance comparison)

I did a quick, informal comparison of the original code, the Dictionary approach, and the RangeVariantRange version. I timed each with the VBA Timer function. For input data, I pasted repeated copies of the original data to create 6534 rows.

The times below are the start and end times for each, reported as seconds (for a fair comparison, I stopped the clock before the popup in the Dictionary approach so it would time just the calculation, not my reaction time).

As the OP noted, the original code was slow, taking almost 90 seconds. Both the Dictionary and the Variant versions took 0.05 seconds. Repeating the tests with 4 copies of the data (26,136 rows) showed a trivial difference, 0.25 seconds vs. 0.09 seconds, respectively. I saw no reason to run the original code on the expanded dataset, that would have been painful. (I've left testing the other approaches to anyone who is interested. Please post your results.)

Looks like either of the tested solutions will give you a performance boost. I'll have to look into using the Dictionary. It seems a lot more powerful than I'd realized.

```
Results:

n = 6534 rows

Original
 42627.06 
 42716.75 
Delta: 89.69 seconds

CalcTotalsDict
 43016.52 
 43016.57 
Delta: 0.05 seconds

RangeVariantVersion
 42774.64 
 42774.69 
Delta: 0.05 seconds


n = 26136 rows

CalcTotalsDict
 44209.46 
 44209.71 
Delta: 0.25 seconds

RangeVariantVersion
 44186.82 
 44186.91 
Delta: 0.09 seconds

CalcTotalsDict
 44209.46 
 44209.71 
Delta: 0.25 seconds
```

#### Original

It seems to me the question is really about performance ("it is really slow"). Any time you're processing a large range, it's easy to boost performance dramatically:

- Copy the input range to a variant (it will become a 2-D array)
- Process the variant, storing results in an output variant
- Copy the output variant to the output range

For Excel to go back and forth between the range/worksheet and the VBA requires substantial Windows overhead. This process makes that trip once in each direction, so the overhead is minimal. I use this process whenever I'm dealing with more than a handful of cells. Note you don't need to `Dim` the variants as arrays, because a variant can hold an array. But you do need to `Redim` the output array before writing to it so that you can address individual elements, just as you would in any other array.

I suspect @BigBen is right, this could probably be done with just worksheet formulas, but I think this "range to variant and back to range" process is worth understanding. Be warned: when the input range copied is a single cell, the variant is a scalar. Trying to access it with array notation in that case will generate an error.

Here's one way:

```
Sub Calculate()  ' Can't use Go() because Go is an Excel keyword
    ' It's good practice to Dim all variables
    Dim Page1 As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, i As Long, vntContent As Variant, vntOutput As Variant
    Dim vntPrices As Variant, nPriceRow As Integer, nPriceCol As Integer, rngData As Range
    
    ' Count the rows
    Set Page1 = Worksheets("Sheet6")
    LastRow = Page1.Cells(Page1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rngData = Page1.Cells(1, 8).Resize(3, 3)  ' Price table
    vntPrices = rngData
    
    Set rngData = Page1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 4)  ' Input range
    vntContent = rngData
    ReDim vntOutput(1 To LastRow, 1 To 1)
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        ' Determine the price lookup column
        Select Case vntContent(i, 3)
            Case "good"
                nPriceCol = 2
            Case "bad"
                nPriceCol = 3
            Case Else
                nPriceCol = 0
        End Select
        
        ' Determine the price lookup row
        Select Case vntContent(i, 2)
            Case "fruit"
                nPriceRow = 2
            Case "salad"
                nPriceRow = 3
            Case Else
                nPriceRow = 0
        End Select
        
        ' If both are valid, calculate price * stock
        If nPriceRow > 0 And nPriceCol > 0 Then
            vntOutput(i, 1) = vntPrices(nPriceRow, nPriceCol) * vntContent(i, 4)
        Else
            vntOutput(i, 1) = "Error"
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Write the output to the P*S column
    Set rngData = Page1.Cells(1, 5).Resize(LastRow, 1)
    rngData = vntOutput
End Sub
```

Comment: your way is really really fast! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### A VBA Lookup

[image]

**Using a Dictionary**

- Should be more efficient (faster) than the Application.Match solution. Your feedback is welcome.

```vb
Sub CalcTotalsDict()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Page 1")
    
    Dim srg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim lPrices(), lTypes(), lStates(), lrCount As Long, lcCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("H1").CurrentRegion
        lrCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        lcCount = .Columns.Count - 1
        lTypes = .Resize(lrCount, 1).Offset(1).Value
        lStates = .Resize(1, lcCount).Offset(, 1).Value
        lPrices = .Resize(lrCount, lcCount).Offset(1, 1).Value
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, lStr As String
    
    For lr = 1 To lrCount
        For lc = 1 To lcCount
            lStr = CStr(lTypes(lr, 1)) & "@" & CStr(lStates(1, lc))
            If Not dict.Exists(lStr) Then
                dict(lStr) = lPrices(lr, lc)
            End If
        Next lc
    Next lr
                
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, sStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sStr = CStr(sData(r, 2)) & "@" & CStr(sData(r, 3))
        If dict.Exists(sStr) Then
            dData(r, 1) = dict(sStr) * sData(r, 4)
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = "Error"
        End If
    Next r

    srg.Columns(5).Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Totals calculated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Using Application.Match**

```vb
Sub CalcTotalsMatch()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Page 1")
    
    Dim srg As Range, rCount As Long

    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim sData(): sData = srg.Value
    
    Dim lPrices(), lTypes(), lStates(), lrCount As Long, lcCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("H1").CurrentRegion
        lrCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        lcCount = .Columns.Count - 1
        lTypes = .Resize(lrCount, 1).Offset(1).Value
        lStates = .Resize(1, lcCount).Offset(, 1).Value
        lPrices = .Resize(lrCount, lcCount).Offset(1, 1).Value
    End With
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim lrIndex, lcIndex, r As Long, IsFound As Boolean
    Dim sType As String, sState As String, sStock As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sType = CStr(sData(r, 2))
        lrIndex = Application.Match(sType, lTypes, 0)
        If IsNumeric(lrIndex) Then
            sState = CStr(sData(r, 3))
            lcIndex = Application.Match(sState, lStates, 0)
            If IsNumeric(lcIndex) Then
                IsFound = True
            End If
        End If
        If IsFound Then
            sStock = sData(r, 4)
            dData(r, 1) = lPrices(lrIndex, lcIndex) * sStock
            IsFound = False
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = "Error"
        End If
    Next r

    srg.Columns(5).Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Totals calculated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

### EDIT: Refactored (Dictionary)

**Main**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Calculates totals...
' Calls:        GetJoinedColumnRanges
'                   GetSingleColumn
'               GetSingleColumn
'               DictJoinedTables
'               GetMultipliedUniques
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub CalcTotals()

    Const WS_NAME As String = "Page 1"
    Const LKP_FIRST_CELL As String = "H1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Dim sUniqueColumns(): sUniqueColumns = Array(2, 3)
    Const SRC_COUNT_COLUMN As Long = 4
    Const DST_COLUMN As Long = 5
    Const UNIQUE_DELIMITER As String = "@"
    Const NO_MATCH_STRING As String = "Error"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim suData():
    suData = GetJoinedColumnRanges(rg, sUniqueColumns, UNIQUE_DELIMITER)
    Dim scData(): scData = GetSingleColumn(rg, SRC_COUNT_COLUMN)
    
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = ws.Range(LKP_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
    Dim lDict As Object: Set lDict = DictJoinedTable(lrg, UNIQUE_DELIMITER)
        
    Dim dData():
    dData = GetMultipliedUniques(suData, scData, lDict, NO_MATCH_STRING)
    
    rg.Columns(DST_COLUMN).Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Totals calculated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Get Joined Column Ranges**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the joined ('Delimiter') columns ('ColumnIndexes')
'               of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based single-column array.
' Calls:        GetSingleColumn
' Date:         2023
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetJoinedColumnRanges( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal ColumnIndexes As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
As Variant
    
    Dim LB As Long: LB = LBound(ColumnIndexes)
    
    Dim sData(), dData(), n As Long, r As Long, rCount As Long
    
    For n = LB To UBound(ColumnIndexes)
        If n = LB Then
            dData = GetSingleColumn(rg.Columns(ColumnIndexes(n)))
            rCount = UBound(dData, 1)
        Else
            sData = GetSingleColumn(rg.Columns(ColumnIndexes(n)))
            For r = 1 To rCount
                dData(r, 1) = dData(r, 1) & Delimiter & CStr(sData(r, 1))
            Next r
        End If
    Next n
    
    GetJoinedColumnRanges = dData

End Function
```

**Get Single Column**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a column ('ColumnIndex')
'               of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based single-column array.
' Date:         2023
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetSingleColumn( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    
    Dim Data()
    
    With rg.Columns(ColumnIndex)
        If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With

    GetSingleColumn = Data

End Function
```

**Joined Table To Dictionary**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a table with the first column of row labels and the first
'               row of column labels, returns the joined label combinations
'               in the keys, and each associated value in the items
'               of a dictionary.
' Date:         2023
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function DictJoinedTable( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
As Object
    
    Dim Data(): Data = rg.Value
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
   
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, kStr As String
   
    For r = 2 To rCount
        For c = 2 To cCount
            kStr = Data(r, 1) & Delimiter & Data(1, c)
            If Not dict.Exists(kStr) Then
                dict(kStr) = Data(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        Set DictJoinedTable = dict
    End If
    
End Function
```

**Get Multiplied Uniques**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Looks for each value of a 2D one-based array ('UniqueData')
'               in the keys of a dictionary ('LookupDictionary') to return
'               the product of the associated item and the value in another
'               same-sized 2D one-based array ('MultiplyData') in the resulting
'               same-sized 2D one-based array. If not found, instead
'               of the product, a string ('NoMatchString') is returned.
' Date:         2023
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetMultipliedUniques( _
    ByVal UniqueData As Variant, _
    ByVal MultiplyData As Variant, _
    ByVal LookupDictionary As Object, _
    ByVal NoMatchString As String) _
As Variant
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(MultiplyData, 1)
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, sStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sStr = UniqueData(r, 1)
        If LookupDictionary.Exists(sStr) Then
            dData(r, 1) = LookupDictionary(sStr) * MultiplyData(r, 1)
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = NoMatchString
        End If
    Next r

    GetMultipliedUniques = dData

End Function
```